# Why doesn't docker tomcat doesn't override a war properties file with a properties file from a shared dir?

Tags: tomcat, properties, configuration, docker, shared-libraries

I'm starting up a Tomcat docker container with the following docker script:

```
FROM tomcat:7-jre7

#Get the config into the shared directory before the tomcat classloader does a sweep - kill tomcat for now
CMD ["catalina.sh", "stop"]

#Override the properties with a shared dir
ADD catalina.properties /usr/local/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties

ADD application.properties /usr/local/tomcat/properties/application.properties

ADD application.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Where [this is the standard Catalina properties file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/conf/catalina.properties).

And this is the only line I've changed:

```
shared.loader=/usr/local/tomcat/properties
```

Other pieces of information - there is a slightly version of `application.properties` in the root level of the war file.

What I want is for the `application.properties` in the properties directory to override the one in the war file.

What I'm seeing is that the version of the `application.properties` in the war file always overrides the one in the shared properties directory.

Now I can get this to work on a vanilla redhat instance. But not in Docker.

My question is: **Why doesn't docker tomcat doesn't override a war properties file with a properties file from a shared dir?**

Comment: Is it possible you also need `<Loader delegate="true"/>`? Per http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html it looks like the loader order you are looking for.

Comment: Good question - but I had it working on my non-docker RHEL instance without that.

Comment: It would be helpful to confirm and post the versions of applications as a well (Docker, Tomcat, RHEL). Is it possible RHEL Tomcat startup script is reading additional configuration `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat7` where the Docker image does not?